# PHP Server time is behind local time

Tags: php, magento, time

my server time is ahead of my local time (I cannot change my server time) by about 4 hours. The server is hosted in a different time zone, and changing the server time would have too many far reaching effects on too many other things.

Anyways, I have customers that place an order for a Gift Card for instance, and the gift card is dated to be sent out the same day that they ordered it, so the date stamp that gets placed on the Gift Card is (for instance), 1/3/2018.

But, let's say they placed the gift card order at 11:30 PM, and the server time has already moved onto 1/4/2018. My code below does not account for that:

```
$curDate  = date('Y-m-d');
if ($card->getCardStatus() == 0){
    if ((($card->getMailDeliveryDate() == null) || ($curDate == $card->getMailDeliveryDate())) && $card->getCardType() != 'offline') {
        $card->setCardStatus(1);
        $card->save();
        $card->send();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to take this scenario into account?

Thank you.

***Edit*** Awh man, I got my question reversed around. My local time is ahead of my server time. I apologize. My Magento is set to eastern time (where I'm at) but the server itself is located in LA, thus PST. I don't want to change the timezone, I just want to make sure that orders placed in other time zones are accounted for.

Comment: i think it's timezone issue.change your tiimezone check. http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-setup-timezone-tutorial/

Comment: Instead of using local time, store and use `time()`. You can convert `time()` into the user's local time on the client-side.

Answer (score 4):

This is where the `PHP` `date_default_timezone_set()` function steps in.

> date_default_timezone_set — Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

Set the `default_timezone` like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

More here [http://php.net/date-default-timezone-set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

**EDIT:**  As suggested by @RamKesavan, you can also set the timezone in `Magento settings` by doing this:

- First set `global timezone` to `GMT` or `UTC`:

  1.) Go to System -> Settings

  2.) Edit your default scope

  3.) Go to Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale Options

  4.) Select GMT Standard Time (or UTC)
- Then you need to set your `default website scope` to your `preferred time zone` like this:

  1.) Go to System -> Settings

  2.) Select the scope for each of your websites.

  3.) Go to Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale Options again.

  4.) Select W. European Standard Time (Europe/Berlin or Europe/Amsterdam) or select some other timezone appropriate for the location of your customers.

  5.)Repeat for the next website.

> The `default website scope` will ensure that your websites display Dutch, Chinese or American order and shipping times, or some other time according to your settings.

More here [https://support.hypernode.com/magento-utc-hypernode](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-utc-hypernode/).

**EDIT 2:** (OP changed the question)

It is impossible to detect the user date time locale settings with accuracy from the server side (`PHP`). This is what the client side (`javascript`) is used for.

There is a `javascript` script available [jstimezonedetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) which is used to easily detect the user time zone settings. Download the script and include it in the page where you have the `purhase form`.

To retrieve the `timezone` and send it with the `purchase form` you can add a `hidden field` inside the `purchase form` (it will be sent with the form) like this:

```
var tz = jstz.determine(); // call the jstimezonedetect script object
var tzName = tz.name();    // name of the user timezone 'Europe/Berlin'
var hiddenTimezone = document.getElementById('myHiddenTimezone');
hiddenTimezone.value = tzName;  // add timezone value to hidden field
```

And in `HTML` you would need to have the `hidden element` added inside the `purchase form` like this:

```
<form ...>
  // ...
  // ...
  <input type="hidden" id="myHiddenTimezone" name="userTimezone" value="" />
  <!-- since the hidden element is inside the form and has a name -->
  <!-- it will be sent with the form -->
  // ...
</form>
```

On the `server side` (receiving side) you would get the `timezone` like this:

```
$userTimezone = $_POST['userTimezone'];  // or $_GET['userTimezone'] if form method was GET
```

When a `purchase` occurs, you now have the `server time` and the `user timezone`. You can make 3 columns in your table. One for `server time`, another for `user time zone` and the third the `current (calculated) user time`.

You can then extract whichever column you wish and you would know for sure what you are getting from the database and how to write a `PHP function` to handle it.

**EDIT 3:**

To simply convert the a date from for example PST to EST you would do this:

```
$ESTDate = new DateTime('2017-02-04 12:32:43', new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$ESTDate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

If you wish to `echo` the `datetime` with formatting:

```
echo $ESTDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If you wish to compare to another date you can use:

```
$difference = $ESTDate1->diff($ESTDate2);
```

which will produce results like this:

```
DateInterval Object
(
  [y] => 3
  [m] => 5
  [d] => 15
  [h] => 0
  [i] => 0
  [s] => 0
  [invert] => 0
  [days] => 1264
)

// usage
if($difference['days'] == 0)
// ...
```

Or you can use the `>` `<` and other operators like this:

```
// both dates must be in the same format (example: 'Y-m-d h:i:s')
if( $ESTDate1 > $ESTDate2)  // date1 is greater
else                        // date2 is greater or equal
```

Comment: in megento there is a option for set application time zone .

Comment: Awh man, I got my question reversed around. My local time is ahead of my server time. I apologize. My Magento is set to eastern time (where I'm at) but the server itself is located in LA, thus PST. I don't want to change the timezone, I just want to make sure that orders placed in other time zones are accounted for.

Comment: @JamesAnderson well do you have information on where the order takes place? If you do, it is easy to add/subtract x hours to the date-time you are getting based on purchase location. If this is your problem I'll add an example of this in my answer.

Comment: @Ivan86 All orders are entered with the timestamp based on the eastern time zone, the data being placed into the database into MailDeliveryDate field. So when I do time and date functions in PHP, that sometimes won't match up with the date that was entered because of timezone differences between EST and PST.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Ok, I have an answer, I will edit my answer above to include it. It will be at the bottom under `Edit 2`.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Ok, check Edit 2, I think it answers your question. Long story short, you can't detect the `user timezone settings` from the `server side`, you will need help from the `client side` (`javascript`) and then send the timezone information with the `purchase`. After you  receive the purchase you can calculate the `current user time` based on the difference in the `server and user timezones`. And then store all the information in the database (3 columns: server time, user time, user time zone)). It's easy later to work with the data knowing what you are working  with.

Comment: @JamesAnderson if this answer doesn't completely solve your problem let me know.

Comment: @JamesAnderson If you have the current user time stamp and user timezone then it is easy to work with the data (you know how to convert it to your time and yet have a current user time stamp, you have it all)

Comment: @JamesAnderson After reading your comment once again I see you would like to just convert the PST to EST? That is simple. If this is the case I will update my answer.

Comment: @James did my answer solve your problem? If so consider accepting it so the question can be closed. If it didn't solve your problem you can write your own answer on how you solved it and accept it. peace